# Valid ARM endpoint not available in Azure Dashboard ARM Data Tile

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-dashboard

**Goal**: Display the latest deployed version off an App Service on an Azure Dashboard to create a view of version deployed per environment

**Method**: Using the "ARM Data" tile in Azure Dashboard, get a list of the deployments and filter on the key information using the JSON path

**Results**:

- `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}?api-version=2023-01-01`

  - Returns a payload of data describing my App Service
  - This proves the principle that we can get levels of information, but does not allow us to get the deployment data
- `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/deployments?api-version=2022-03-01`

  - Fails validation in the portal as "Only valid ARM endpoints are supported"
  - [image]
  - If I am reading the docs correctly, this is a [valid ARM endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-deployments?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01#deployment)

**Advice sought**:

- Can anyone see any obvious problems with the approach we are following?
- Does anyone have any ideas how we could create that dashboard view of App version per environment if this doesn't work?

Comment: Try checking the deployments using [`az deployment mg list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/mg?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-mg-list). Have you checked it? @Al Mills

Comment: We can get the deployment information elsewhere, yes - but cannot pull this through to a dashboard.